# Freeze header and footer but with vertical both scroll bars on content visible always

Tags: html, css

I have a need to display a large amount of data in a small space. I have a header and footer with column names and the data in a "content" div. I would like to "freeze" the header and footer to allow horizontal scrolling of the entire table but keep the vertical scroll bars of the content div visible at all times, despite the horizontal scroll position on the wrapper.

Is this possible? Would I need to dig into something like jQuery to accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
        <div id="row">Row</div>
        <div id="alt">Alt</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Layout */
#header, #content, #footer { width: 900px; }
#content { height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; }
#wrapper { width: 400px; overflow-x: auto; }

/* Visual */
#row { background-color: #EEE; }
#alt { background-color: #AAA; }
#header, #footer { border: solid 1px #000; font-weight: 700; }
#row, #alt { padding: 1px; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuxur/3/

Comment: Does your #header and #footer need to be as wide as the content?

Comment: If you're displaying tabular data, shouldn't you be using a table?

Comment: Also, `id`s should be unique.

Comment: Yes, there will be roughly 20 columns, at 100px width each. The header and footer columns need to match this.

Comment: kei, I could use a table but I suspect I'll have the same issue. IDs in this example are only duplicated for simplicity.

Comment: @orange kid: Does the wrapper have a set height? or does it cover 100% of the page?

Comment: +1 because I realized this question is a fair bit more difficult than I had originally thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your markup a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vuxur/6/

HTML:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
            <div>Row</div>
            <div>Alt</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Layout */
#header, #content > div, #footer { width: 900px; }
#content { height: 200px; width: 400px; overflow-y: auto; }
#content > div { overflow-x: auto; }
#wrapper { width: 400px; border: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; }

/* Visual */
#content > div > div:nth-child(2n-1) { background-color: #EEE; }
#content > div > div:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #AAA; }
#header, #footer { border: solid 1px #000; font-weight: 700; }
#row, #alt { padding: 1px;
```

Comment: This looks good but my headers and footers need to horizontally scroll with content too.

Comment: I think I made some error when updating. I just updated my answer. 

p/s: Removed the #row and #alt references. CSS `:nth-child` psedoclass does even/odd selection.

Comment: question? isn't :nth-child only supported by modern browsers? ie8, 9, opera, ff, chrome, etc. isn't that going to be a problem with IE7?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vuxur/7/ (changed URL again, check). The new technique involves absolutely positioning the #header and #footer, and adding top and bottom paddings to the #content.

Comment: @Jason: I don't believe watering down content to suit users using non-standards compliant browsers. Should support be added, use jQuery to do it, like `$('#content > div:odd').addClass('.odd')` and modify the CSS to `div:nth-child(2n-1), div.odd { ... }`

Comment: @teddy, that might work. Let me play around with it a bit and I'll post back later. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that it's impossible (can someone correct me if I'm wrong) to have horizontal scolling enabled while the vertical scrollbars don't apply to the #header and the #footer - try comparing http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vuxur/6/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vuxur/7/

Comment: Here you go.. based on what teddyrised did and ojkid's description: http://jsfiddle.net/bNsZ3/

Comment: Ah, that's an ingenious solution, Kei! I was actually thinking of doing margins and fixed positioning, but looks like jQuery is the simpler way out :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this easily by setting their `position` property to be: `position: fixed`, which functions like absolute positioning, but relative to the viewport, not the page, meaning that they will not move with scrolling of the rest of the page.

```
#header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** As the above doesn't work out, as pointed out in comments, due to the wrapper div, I believe that the best way to do it would be with javascript, and absolute positioning - I'm not sure there's an HTML/CSS-only way to do it. You'd just update the CSS above to read `position: absolute`, and modify the top/bottom values based on the viewport location.

Comment: Relative to the viewport being the wrapper? Setting fixed position pulled header and footer out of the wrapper completely.

Comment: Not really since the list in contained in a wrapper and not in a body. If it was body, then it would be simple. Yes...

Comment: @Orange+Robert: Ah, ok then - never mind, fixed positioning wouldn't work for that, anyway.